# ReactJS with ES6 class in state: change only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm totally newbie to ReactJS and there is a little strange behaviour when I created counter app

https://jsfiddle.net/8f5tqr74/2/

```
class CounterViewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 5;
    }

    tick() {
        //cannot move logic of this method to sendTick complex logic will be here
        this.value++;
    }

}

var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return new CounterViewModel();
    },

    sendTick: function () {
         console.log("Before:",this.state);

         var stateObj = this.state;
         stateObj.tick();
         this.setState(stateObj);
         console.log("After:",this.state);
    },

    render: function () {
        return <div>
            {this.state.value}
            <button onClick={this.sendTick}>Increase</button>
        </div>
    }


});


ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

My problem is
This code works only first time when I click button
After I've got this in Developer console

```
//first click
Before: CounterViewModel {value: 5}
After: CounterViewModel {value: 6}
//second click
Before: Object {value: 6}
```

In second click class of state is flushed to Object, however I didn't make manipulations in this object

My questions are:

1) Why does React flush class of object after setState?

2) Why doesn't React flush class object after getInitialState?

3) How can I put complex logic into state object in React? I know I can recreate object with increased value and all will be work well (see code below)

```
class CounterViewModel {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return new CounterViewModel(5);
    },

    sendTick: function () {
        this.setState(new CounterViewModel(this.state.value+1))
    },

    render: function () {
        return <div>
            {this.state.value}
            <button onClick={this.sendTick}>Increase</button>
        </div>
    }


});


ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2):

React expects `state` to be a plain JS object, that's the reason why it becomes an object after you call `setState()`.

Also, `setState` does not immediately mutate `this.state`, which means that when it prints in your code

```
After: CounterViewModel {value: 6}
```

the `state` didn't really change, if you move that console.log() to the callback function of `setState` like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f5tqr74/4/), you'll notice that after the state changes, `state` becomes a plain object

```
Before: CounterViewModel {value: 5}
After: Object {value: 6}
```

**So how do you fix that?**

You have use a plain object as `state` and you have to treat it like an **immutable** object.

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {counter: new CounterViewModel()}
    },

    sendTick: function () {
        var stateObj = Object.assign(new CounterViewModel(),this.state.counter); // Deep clone
        stateObj.tick();
        this.setState({counter: stateObj});
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log(this.state);
        return <div>
            {this.state.counter.value}
            <button onClick={this.sendTick}>Increase</button>
        </div>
    }


});
```

[working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8f5tqr74/5/)

Comment: I recommend that you do not store the mutable counter instance directly in the component state. Instead just copy the counter's `value` property to the component state

Comment: That's okay as well! But that won't fit the third question which was "How can I put complex logic into state object in React" :-P

Answer (score 2):

QoP is correct, React expects the state to be a vanilla JavaScript Object. Where my answer deviates from his/hers is that I do not copy the `CounterViewModel` instance to the component's state.

It's pretty gunky using the separate class like you are, so interacting with it will be a little ugly. And why are you using `class` syntax for your other code but the old React syntax for the React component ?

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    // call parent constructor
    super(props)
    // create an instance of counter view model
    // save it as a normal instance property (not the same as `this.props`)
    this.counter = new CounterViewModel()
    // set initial state using the instance's counter value
    // do NOT copy the counter object directly to state
    this.state = { counter: this.counter.value }
  }
  sendTick (event) {
    // mutate your counter object
    this.counter.tick()
    // set the component state with the counter's value
    this.setState({ counter: this.counter.value })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.value}
        // note the slight difference in the way I set onClick
        // read more: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding
        <button onClick={e=> this.sendTick(e)}>Increase</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter
```